# Django not installing with pip because of mismatched hash

Tags: python, django, pip

I have a virtual machine set up with a directory created with virtualenv (env2). I am inside this directory and have it activated and want to instal django 1.4. This is my command:

```
$ pip install django==1.4
```

But it returns saying that the hashes don't match. The thing is, they do match though. Anyone know my problem?

Comment: Always include actual error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can give pip a specific url to a tar.gz to install from, for example:

```
pip install https://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/1.4/Django-1.4.5.tar.gz
```

Just find one without the faulty hash.